# WooCommerce add Read more button for Product list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I use WooCommerce and in my product lists, the user will link to the product page after they click a picture or title.

I want to add ” read more ” button right after my short description in the product list, something like read more button for blogs

I found what page I must add PHP code, I also add this code to my `functions.php`

```php
function read_more() {
    global $product;
    if ($product){
        $url = esc_url($product->get_permalink() );
        echo '<a rel="nofollow" href="' .$url .'" class="read_more">read_more</a>';
    }
}
```

then I add this code to my product list template :

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','read_more');
```

but nothing adds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in your active theme `functions.php` file

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'read_more' );

function read_more() {
    global $product;
    if ( $product ) {
        $url = esc_url( $product->get_permalink() );
        echo '<a rel="nofollow" href="' . $url . '" class="read_more">read_more</a>';
    }
}
```